# Automate the laravel homestead to reload my Homestead.yaml configurations

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, vagrant, homestead

After installing the homestead and adding the box, and configured the Homestead.yaml that contains the url `homestead.app`

After doing an `up` and `ssh`, going to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` the `homestead.app` was there.

So I changed the `homestead.app` into `site.daison.app` in my Homestead.yaml from my hosts and doing a `homestead halt` and `homestead up` again and `ssh` just to reload my configurations as I thought.

Going back to the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` the `homestead.app` still remain.

So what I did is to destroy my homestead using the command `homestead destroy` and doing the `up` and `ssh` again going back to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` the config `site.daison.app` is now there.

Question:
Is there a way to do this and reload my homestead configurations instead of destroying it and doing things again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the directory where you homestead is created. Type in the terminal

```
vagrant provision
```

Homestead is just a predefined vagrant-box.

Documentation:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#daily-usage

Comment: Thank you for the headsup, I didn't see that thing, hmmm!